# how to explicitly remove cpu limits for a container?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to remove cpu limits for a specific container where the namespace has default cpu limits (via limitrange).
Per [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/#what-if-you-specify-a-container-s-request-but-not-its-limit) the default value will be assigned.
When I explicitly set limits.cpu to 0, I got an error that tells me requests value 20m should be less than or equal to limits value.

So is it possible to force no limits in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, it is not possible to achieve. It does make sense to me it is not possible as stated by Frank Gu: **because that would pretty much defeat the purpose of resource quotas in the first place**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can remove limits with `null` value.
At least it worked from helmfile:

```
   resources:
    requests:
      memory: "100Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
    limits:
      memory: "100Mi"
      cpu: null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the CPU limits to 0, then you will be getting <= 0 CPU resources. As per the link to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/#what-if-you-specify-a-container-s-request-but-not-its-limit) you have originally included, **you should just set the request and not set the limit at all**. That will set inform the scheduler of the pod's resource request. If your namespace has a CPU limit set, then the limit will be defaulted to that if it's not explicitly stated; otherwise, there will be no limit set.

Comment: So how to force no limits if the namespace has default value?

Comment: If your namespace has CPU limits, then that's probably there for good reason and is usually set by the Cluster Admin to enforce resource allocation. If you have not explicitly set a namespace CPU limit, then there shouldn't be one.

Comment: I'm the cluster-admin and I set default limits for the good reasons. I just wanna exclude one specific container from this default value.

Comment: Haha! I don't think there would be a way, because that would pretty much defeat the purpose of resource quotas in the first place. Sorry I couldn't help you here, but do let me know if there is a solution!